# QT creator - issues getting started

Tags: qt

Just finished my python course and trying to get started making GUI applications.  Downloaded the open source QT.  Running into problems off the bat.

I make a new python window application, and keep getting the import error: No module named PySide2.QtWidgets

As I'm new to QT I don't know what to do.  Tried reinstalling, and searched QT's forum and FAQ's.  Anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Have you checked if you have installed PySide2 for the right version of Python interpreter? You can issue `which python` to see the location of python and `python -v` to know the exact version. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69752/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyside might be of help.

Comment: python 3.7.3 pyside2 5.12.3